# I would like a vanilla powder type to substitute for cocoa powder

Tags: baking

I do not like chocolate. I have a recipe for chocolate energy bites. What can substitute for cocoa powder?

Comment: Welcome! If you could [edit] your post with the recipe, our community can come up with better ideas - it’s a huge difference if the cocoa is a main ingredient or just a minor detail. While you wait for an answer, I recommend you take the time for the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: You can purchase vanilla powder.  As @Stephie points out, if we know the recipe, we might be able to help you decide if it can work and how much to add.

Comment: To use as a substitute for cocoa powder in chocolate energy bites, I would suggest milk powder.

Comment: @BackyardChef no answers in comments, please...

Comment: We really need the whole recipe to be able to help. I'd suggest vanilla whey protein powder, but without knowing the rest of the ingredients (eggs, other moisture-retaining ingredients?), you could very well end up with an inedible brick, wasted time, and wasted money.

Comment: Proportions are crucial in baking, so please post the whole recipe so we can suggest an adequate substitute